# SSO - another application user wants to access my application

Tags: authentication, spring-security, single-sign-on, spring-session, spring-security-kerberos

I have two applications called like app1 and app2. both apps have there own users separately. 
Now suppose user with user-name usr1 from app1 logged into app1. Now he want to access app2 without logging into app2. My clients are not interested to use any IDP like okta, ssoCircle, oneLogin and so on.

Is there any way to give access usr1 on app2 without login into app2?  user will only login into app1 and he will get access to app2.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This seems like a recipe for trouble. Are they thinking about guest access? Which kind of authorization are they thinking?

Comment: app2 is developed using spring.

Comment: @efekctive - usr1 will act as an authenticated user in app2. When usr1 will try to access app2, I need to verify that usr1 is already logged into app1. Otherwise I will deny usr1 from app2.

Comment: Your solution is worse than the problem. How does app2 know about the authorization?

Comment: @efekctive - in app2, there are some fixed specific default  authorization role to access the app2 for app1 users. Please don't think about the authorization, just think about the authentication. My main concern is how I can verify that the usr1 verified user in app1 and usr1 is already logged in app1 during accessing the app2.

Comment: I believe you should drop this idea. Logging off

Comment: So how did you finally solve this problem?

Comment: @HarshadVyawahare - We have developed separate micro service like IDP. It serves the app1 and app2 for authorization and authentication. Also we have implemented a SDK for communication with IDP by the app1 and app2.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access second app without login, then JWT is the best solution. Though your question is not clear like are both apps using Java/Spring, why your client is not willing to use SSO?

Comment: both apps are on spring. both apps are live. Both are using different db, server, domain. Client is not willing to use any IDP server. as if we use IDP, we need to transfer the apps user table to IDP server.